# How can I get Column index of grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to get column index of a `DataGridView` inside the `CellEndEdit` event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndex = dataGridViewMsg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

Just do

```
private void dataGridView1_CennEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
}
```

That will give you the column index of the cell currently being edited.

Though you would probably just want to use `e.ColumnIndex` for whatever it is you want to do to save the overhead of creating a new variable.  It isn't clear from your question what the end goal is.

Comment: I would appreciate that!  Glad it helped!  Happy Coding.